# What is the best practice of variable scope, in relation to React / Typescript performance?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Working with typescript / react, I'm trying to up my skills regarding best practices and design, and therefore I'm wondering what is the best practice regarding code where a small function (or class), is called a large amount of times, would it performance wise be better to place a variable outside the function? Consider the following example:

I have a map which maps some enum value to a string:

```
const complexityClassNameMap = new Map<TC, string>();
complexityClassNameMap.set(TC.O1, 'excellent');
complexityClassNameMap.set(TC.ON, 'good');
complexityClassNameMap.set(TC.OLOGN, 'fair');
complexityClassNameMap.set(TC.ONLOGN, 'fair');
```

I have a function `Col` which is called around 10k times (as part of constructing a very large table):

```
const Col = (props: ComplexityColProps) => {
  return (
    <td className={complexityClassNameMap.get(props.complexity)}>
      {complexityDescrMap.get(props.complexity)}
    </td>
  );
};
```

Normally i would put a variable close to where it is used as a best practice, however in this particular use case, would this cost a lot of performance?, and hence would it be better to leave `const complexityClassNameMap` in outer scope?

Comment: I ask because performance should usually be your last concern.  Writing clean and understandable code is usually more important.  If you're basically building an `enum` that should be remain outside of the scope of the function regardless.  If you're calling that function 10K times and worried about performance, a better solution may be to use pagination or a similar idea (infinite scrolling).

Comment: That being said, yes building the map dynamically every time the function is called will be less performant.  The amount would depend on your application and how simplified this example is.  With the small example you posted, loading the data will probably be a bigger bottle neck than rebuilding the map for every row.  However, I still feel like it would be cleaner to define that Map outside of the function scope, but nearby (same file or class) if it's only used there.